# why Firebase authentication doesn't work without google dns?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, dns

Sorry for my english...
I'm using firebase authentication for first the first time.
I discovered that I cannot create/connect to accounts if my network automatically selects dns and does not use google dns(8.8.8) 
I do not understand how my application will work (just I think that not everyone uses this DNS). 
Is there any way to fix this so it works for everyone?or is it work correctly?
[without google dns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSPBw.png)
[with google dns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iKR4.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In your case: please don't use images to show errors or code, and describe what are you doing, please edit post to write what are you doing, what is your code, what is the error and what have you tried to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check any that applies to you,
Is your ISP is blocking DNS queries to Google Authentication servers,
Are you using a proxy, if yes try disabling it, and then try again,
Check the error returned in auth callback when you are requesting authentication,
Check stack trace in LogCat of Android Studio.

Comment: i can't check which error is returned from callback , because function dont work without internet. I have tried. Without google dns the  internet in emulator doesn't work... 
Also i checked i don't use proxy. 
and check stack trace maybe too dont really without internet in emulator.